# Laravel and Vue emit data from component 1 to component 2 within Blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

No idea if this is possible.

But here is the context.

I have a left navbar with a membership status(active/inactive).
When the payment gateway receives the payment, a webhook is sent via Paddle(Laravel Paddle API).

During the webhook I am redirecting the user to a thank you page(blade with vue component).

app.js

```
let Event = new Vue();
window.Event = Event;
```

navbar.blade.php

```
<componentOne></componentOne>
<componentTwo></componentTwo>
```

ComponentOne

```
    mounted(){
        Event.$emit("updateStatus");
    },
```

ComponentTwo:

```
    mounted() {
        this.fetchStatus();
        Event.$on("updateStatus", () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('testing!');
            }, 4000);
        })
    },
```

I was hoping to catch this even in component 2 but nothing.....

Any idea what I am doing wrong? It is the first time I try to to this within blade.

I know both components are inside a PHP page, but I was hoping that perhaps Vue might still be able to communicate through the app.js somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a race condition where componentOne is emitting the event before componentTwo is mounted so it's not listening yet. Try moving your $on call to created() or even putting a timeout on the $emit. I might be misunderstanding your flow though.

Comment: Please use comments to seek clarification from askers, not answers.

Comment: @miken32 Not sure how suggesting that a race condition could be the culprit is seeking clarification, especially when that's been the issue for me given a similar set of circumstances, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind.